# use JQuery to update a div after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using an AJAX call to delete and item which is working, the trouble I am having is updating the data-table inside a div to reflect the item deletion from the database.

Comment: You have to send the command to php. Php will execute the command once it receives it. Php will process the command and come up withe either the desired value or an error. This will be sent back as a response to your JavaScript. Then u can update.

Comment: I get the response back from my AJAX call just fine, that is not the issue the issue is $('#dataTable').load('includes/datatable.php'); is not updating the div...I want the contents of the div (my data-table #dataTable) to refresh after the ajax callback function is returned successfully.

Comment: I would use hyml() instead of.load()

Comment: so use:  $('#dataTable').html('includes/datatable.php'); instead?

Answer (score 0):

So here the short answer:

```
 if(itemdel=="deleted")
 {
     console.log("get request to datatable");
     //add the absolute url here so with http://xyz.xy/includes/datatable.php
     $.get('includes/datatable.php', function( data ) {
         console.log("data received, data");
         $('#dataTable').html(data);
     });
 }
```

Comment: the short answer does not update anything inside the div...I will keep trying thank you.

Comment: why do you think? its a ajax request to the datatable.php page and in the callback you receive the data and with the .html method you can wirte it in the div on the DOM

[Jquery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: I mean it does nothing after I click Delete, my ajax call removes the record from the MySQL database, the callback function comes back as 'deleted' but your code does not update the div #dataTable.

Comment: can you post the php code too ? try it without the surrounding if statement

Comment: php code has been posted! Thank you!  ThePHP is working...its updating the div #dataTable after the AJAX callback function returns 'deleted' that is the issue.

Comment: ive edited the answer ...

now you should see the messages in the console

Comment: HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)GET - http://easyops.co/dev/inventory/includes/datatable.php
not sure why its getting an error that is the exact path

Answer (score 0):

Here the "long one" try to understand :)

```
var delID = document.getElementById('delID').value;

$('#so-delete').on('click', deleteData); // execute the deleteData function on click // without ()!!! when you put () it will be executed @init

function deleteData() {
    apiCall("includes/deletesoitem.php", "POST", loadData, delID); // makes the request --> loadData function executed after ajax call is successfully finished
}

function loadData(itemdel) {
    if (itemdel == "deleted") {
        alert("SUCCESS: Item Deleted Successfully!");
    //  the "anonymous "callBack" function will be executed after ajax request is finished
        apiCall("includes/datatable.php", "GET", function (msg) {
            $('#dataTable').html(msg);
        });
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param url Request for the URL
 * @param ajaxMethod Request Method (POST/GET/ETC)
 * @param callBack Callback method this method will be executed after     ajax request is successful
 * @param data Request body data
 */
function apiCall(url, ajaxMethod, callBack, data) {
    var requestData = (data != "undefined") ? data : {}; // set request data to data if exists

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: ajaxMethod,
        data: requestData,
        dataType: "text"
    });

    request.done(function (msg) {
        //execute the callback function
        callBack(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
}
```